# Microsoft Word: Auto-filling other form elements basing on contents of first one

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, forms

I'm trying to set up a form in Word that includes several fields that get duplicated in various spots in the document, like First Name, Last Name, etc. I want the user to be able to enter each information once and have it auto-fill for the rest of the instances.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other solution to this problem, than to hire a macro and write a VisualBasic code to do the job for you.

Basically you have to write a code that will react on `onChange` event of first (one) edit box and propagate changes to other ones, by changing their `Text` property. Quite an easy task, if you have any experience with Visual Basic and/or macros.

If you don't have experience with VB for Word, try to solve this problem the easiest possible way. Put two (or more) edit boxes to your document (form) then click "Record Macro", then enter some text to first edit box, then to second (or other) and finally stop recording macro. No, you can find it amoong others, and examine carefully code of just recorded macro. It should clear any doubts you can have.

You can update this macro, to do exactly what you want to do, or even copy/move it to your `normal.dot` tmeplate, so any document created basing on it, will be using your new macro.